# How can I draw a grid onto a tkinter canvas

Tags: python, matplotlib, canvas, tkinter, grid

I am trying to draw a grid on:

```
from matplotlib.figure import 

figure = Figure(figsize=(10, 10))
a = figure.add_subplot(111)
a.plot(x, y, '-r')
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=window)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, plotWindow)
canvas.draw()
```

plotWindow is just a tkinter.Frame object

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: do you need matplot for this ? Plot lines as usually in `matplot`. You can use ie. `x=[0,0] y=[-100,100]` to plot vertical line and ie. `x=[-100,100] y=[0,0]` to plot horiziontal line. `Matplot` has also function [.grid()](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.grid.html) to display grid. But all of this has nothing to do with `tkinter.Canvas`.

Comment: @furas yesm i did try .grid(), but i never .show() my plot so it doesn't work (when it does another window pops out). I do not even use matplotlib.plot, only matplotlib.figure and when I try to use .grid() on a figure it just doesn't work or i lack knowledge to know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't have all your code this is what I'd suggest.

After `a = figure.add_subplot(111)` toss in

```
ax = f.gca()
ax.set_xticks(numpy.arange(0,1,0.5))
```

Then after `canvas =` put in

```
a.grid()
canvas.show()
```

Omit `canvas.draw()`?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, your `figsize` is too large and it pushes off your `NavigationToolbar`. Try the below with minimum changes to your code:

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg,NavigationToolbar2Tk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
window = tk.Canvas(root)
window.pack()
plotWindow = tk.Frame(root)
plotWindow.pack()

figure = Figure(figsize=(5, 5))
a = figure.add_subplot(111)
x=[-100,100]
y=[0,4]
a.plot(x, y, '-r')
a.grid()
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=window)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, plotWindow)
canvas.draw()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]